# How to adjust text label within iOS UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uialertview, sizewithfont

I have been trying hard to adjust label for my UIAlertView, and I am not successful. I want to make it resize correctly as per the string length. I read that there is not much one can do except to subclass it, but when I was about to do it, I found a trick to play with it. (code below)

I could successfully resize it, format fonts etc for small strings. I can fit some of my strings (<1000 chars) nicely, but larger strings (>1000 chars) make it ugly:

- Label just refuses to grow to fit extra content
- Text size does not reduce despite I reducing it (it gets reduced for smaller strings where it's not needed. And it remains bigger where it is needed smaller)
- The label shows with white background (the one seen in IB at design time) for larger strings, with trailing part of strings buried up because larger text.

The whole thing looks completely messed up.

Here is how I sneaked into UIAlertView appearance code:

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UILabel *body = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"]; 

    body.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    // body.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    CGRect  alFrame = body.frame;

    CGFloat pointSize;

    UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10];

    CGSize labelSize = [body.text sizeWithFont:font minFontSize:8   actualFontSize:&pointSize forWidth:alFrame.size.width  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSLog (@"%f", labelSize.height);
    UIFont *actualFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10];
    CGSize sizeWithCorrectHeight = [body.text sizeWithFont:actualFont];

    alFrame.size.height = sizeWithCorrectHeight.height*10;
    NSLog (@"%f - %f", alFrame.size.height, alFrame.size.width);
    body.numberOfLines = 8;
    body.frame = alFrame;
    body.font = actualFont;    
}
```

Note that commented lines are things which I have tried with thousand twists. And uncommented ones too produce the same effect. Smaller text adjust just as I have coded here. I just need a solution that can make my label display all text, irrespective of string length - I know there is plenty of room on it still but it just doesn't resize for larger strings that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hack that I have used successfully in many shipping apps.

1. Use `sizeWithFont` to figure out how much space you need (from the message text).
2. Set the message to an appropriate number of `@"\n"`.
3. Insert a new transparent `UILabel` as a subview of the alert view with your text.

If you need really long texts, you could try inserting a `UITextView`, which theoretically can be scrolled. (Please tell me if it works if you try it.) However, I would strongly advise not to use this design and construct a proper view controller instead.

```
[alertView addSubview:label];
```

Comment: what do you mean by inserting a new UILabel? Will it be subview of alert OR subview of the existing UILabel (with handle _bodyTextLabel)? Can you paste some sample sort of code?

Comment: I tried this approach. The new transparent label didn't solve my issue. However I got the clue and added a new UILabel with desired size as a subview. I hid the original label, which was somehow constrained and never exceeded height of 250 px. I don't know why, but it's internal to UIAlertView. Thanks for the right direction. Upvoted and marked correct.

Comment: One more thing: willpresentalertview doesn't hide actual message label. If you place a view exactly above it, it creates a hiding effect. But you can neither hide it using hidden = YES, nor you can remove it using removefromsuperview. It's something inherent to UIAlertView so cannot be modified.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you need the hack exploiting the transparent background & invisible line breaks.

Comment: This hasn't exactly solved my problem though. I have to place the other view right over where default alert label stays. This causes some limitations in placing other things like an image etc. If I move my view slightly, it will show the original label and mess up things. And there is no way to hide or remove it. Also, as you say, adding my own transparent view will only make the underlying original label visible, which is already useless. What to do?

Comment: I am also afraid that I am specifying exact dimensions instead of relative one, so on different devices it may or may not work, and will expose the original label anyway.

Comment: Maybe you are straining the concept of the alert view. If it is not flexible enough for your needs, you should "roll your own" and create a modal view controller.

Comment: The thing is, I tried but faced issues discarding it. Then I read some design changes in modals as to how iOS treats them, and I was utterly confused. The requirement asks just for an alert, so I did not venture in that area. Do you know of good example of such modal views that can simply replace uialertview without much work? Since I put so many hours into tweaking UIAlertView I am short on time.

Comment: Also, what complicates this is not just the uialertview, but I need a series of them. I chained their appearance using calling them from delegates and all. That is something bit tricky to get away with, if I now sit and redesign it. Do you get me?

Comment: Sure I get it. Still, it is better to invest a little bit more time into the UI architecture upfront and have a flexible and efficient framework for such things later.

Comment: Good point! Any modal view example? I would like to redesign it if I know it works. Maybe it would be simpler than what I am doing right now - maybe without discarding and redisplaying of views, just changing UILabel text strings?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [you should not use the `sizeWithFont...` methods to calculate the size of your `UILabel`s.](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html)

`UILabel` implements the standard UIKit `sizeToFit` and `sizeThatFits:` methods which you should use instead.

If you wish the label to wrap across multiple lines, first set `numberOfLines` to 0. Then use this code to calculate the required size:

```
CGSize requiredSize = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(availableWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
labelFrame.size = requiredSize;
// ...
```

Alternatively, you can set the label's width first, then call `[label sizeToFit]`. It will size itself to fit its current width.

Comment: After setting the width, sizeToFit can change it again, so this is not a good approach. Indeed, sizeToFit and sizeThatFits both do not allow you to specify a width constraint, so they are useless for this problem.

Comment: sizeThatFits may return a smaller width than the constraint you provided. In that case you just explicitly set the width again afterwards.

Comment: Not useful? The standard UIKit method to size a control to its contents is to use sizeThatFits or sizeToFit. These are used all over the place, especially by the new auto-layout stuff with iOS 6. These two methods give you everything you need.